# не применять трансформацию на дочерние элементы

Tags: html, css

я хочу применить трансформацию `skew()`, но сделать так чтобы изображение внутри не трогалось и обрезалось

```css
div{
  display: inline-block; background: gray;
  transform:skew(-20deg);
}

img{
  display:inherit;
  transform:skew(20deg);
}
```

```html
<div>
<a href='#' class='feature deg0'>
  <img src='https://via.placeholder.com/100x100'>
</a>
</div>
```

то есть там где изображение выходит за приделы блока - оно должно быть **обрезано**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для дочерних придётся применять такое же значение, только отрицательное.

Покажу пример на `rotate`, а то `skew` убого смотрится.

```css
.feature {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 2px solid #333;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.feature:hover {
  border-color: #999;
}

.feature, .feature img {transition: all linear 1s;}

.feature.deg45:hover {transform: rotate(45deg);}
.feature.deg135:hover {transform: rotate(135deg);}
.feature.deg180:hover {transform: rotate(180deg);}
.feature.deg225:hover {transform: rotate(225deg);}
.feature.deg315:hover {transform: rotate(315deg);}

.feature.deg45:hover img {transform: rotate(-45deg);}
.feature.deg135:hover img {transform: rotate(-135deg);}
.feature.deg180:hover img {transform: rotate(-180deg);}
.feature.deg225:hover img {transform: rotate(-225deg);}
.feature.deg315:hover img {transform: rotate(-315deg);}
```

```html
<div class='circle-container'>
  <a href='#' class='feature deg0'><img src='https://via.placeholder.com/150x150'></a>
  <a href='#' class='feature deg45'><img src='https://via.placeholder.com/150x150'></a>
  <a href='#' class='feature deg135'><img src='https://via.placeholder.com/150x150'></a>
  <a href='#' class='feature deg180'><img src='https://via.placeholder.com/150x150'></a>
  <a href='#' class='feature deg225'><img src='https://via.placeholder.com/150x150'></a>
  <a href='#' class='feature deg315'><img src='https://via.placeholder.com/150x150'></a>
</div>
```

---

Когда ж я нормально буду читать вопрос -_-
В принципе, суть та же

```css
.circle-container {display: block; background: gray; transform: skewX(15deg); overflow: hidden;}
.reverse {transform: skewX(-15deg);}
```

```html
<div class='circle-container'>
  <div class="reverse">
    <a href='#' class='feature deg0'><img src='https://via.placeholder.com/100x100'></a>
    <a href='#' class='feature deg45'><img src='https://via.placeholder.com/100x100'></a>
    <a href='#' class='feature deg135'><img src='https://via.placeholder.com/100x100'></a>
    <a href='#' class='feature deg180'><img src='https://via.placeholder.com/100x100'></a>
    <a href='#' class='feature deg225'><img src='https://via.placeholder.com/100x100'></a>
    <a href='#' class='feature deg315'><img src='https://via.placeholder.com/100x100'></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Дополнение**
`overflow: hidden;` с этим справляется.

Comment: уточнил вопрос, посмотрите пожалуйста)

Comment: Используйте `overflow: hidden;`, обновил ответ и последний пример рабочий и показывает работу `overflow: hidden;`